# MVC Html.PagedListPager() - How to update current page button?

Tags: ajax, button, model-view-controller, pagination

I have a view that uses `Html.PagedListPager()` to render a pagination control.

It all works fine but the current page button is not updated after the Ajax request has completed successfully.

The `class` attribute of the HTML tag associated with the pagination button should be set to `active`.

How do i do that?

Here's the code that creates the pagination control:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
  Model.Items, 
  page => Url.Action("RenderMessageListItems", new { page }), 
  PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
    new PagedListRenderOptions {Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded},
    new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "OnPageChanged", UpdateTargetId = Model.Name + "Items"}
  )
)
```

Edit:

Perhaps i should return some JSON data (instead of plain HTML page) from the controller that includes the page number. By doing this i would be able to update the concerning button in the OnSuccess Ajax function, but isn't there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Either i don't understand the PagedList library or there is a bug in it that causes it's strange behavior (most likely as the library is 3 years old now). My workaround is as follows which renders the `@Html.PagedListPager()` almost useless and i could have written my own code in the time spent till yet.

**Controller action**

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult RenderMessageListItems(int? page)
{
  ...
  System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Message> lQuery = from m in lDBContext.Messages orderby m.CreateTimestamp select m;

  int lPageNumber = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
  int lPageSize = 5;

  // note: ViewModels.MessageListItems implements IPagedList.IPagedList
  ViewModels.MessageListItems lViewModel = new ViewModels.MessageListItems(lPageNumber, lPageSize, lQuery.Count());

  lQuery = lQuery.Skip(lPageSize * (lPageNumber - 1)).Take(lPageSize);

  foreach (Models.Message lMessage in lQuery)
  {
    ViewModels.MessageListItem lMessageListItem = new ViewModels.MessageListItem();
    lMessageListItem.ID = lMessage.ID;
    lMessageListItem.Date = lMessage.Date;
    lMessageListItem.Caption = lMessage.Caption;
    lMessageListItem.Content = lMessage.Content;

    lViewModel.Add(lMessageListItem);
  }

  return Json(new {page = page, items = RenderRazorViewToString("../Shared/MessageList/Items", lViewModel)}, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Passing the view to the `Json` object caused a circular reference exception on serialization, thus the call to `RenderRazorViewToString()`. The code of this function has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/3936440

**Partial view**

```
...

@* the following include is needed to get Html.PagedListPager() working *@
<script src="@Html.ResourceUrl("Script", "jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive")"></script>

<script>

  function OnPageChanged(jsonObject, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    @* inject new items into message list *@
    $("[name=@{@Model.Name}Items]").html(jsonObject.items);

    @* select all page buttons *@
    var $buttons = $(".pagination li");

    @* get button linked to previous page and... *@
    var $previousButton = $buttons.filter(".active");

    @* remove active indication and... *@
    $previousButton.removeClass("active");

    @* fix missing link attributes of first page button (strangely PagedListPager wont render those) *@
    if ($previousButton.index() == 0)
    {
      var previousPageNumber = $previousButton.index() + 1;

      var $previousLink = $previousButton.find("a");
      $previousLink.attr("data-ajax", true);
      $previousLink.attr("data-ajax-success", "OnPageChanged");
      $previousLink.attr("href", "@Url.Action("RenderMessageListItems")?page=" + previousPageNumber);
    }

    @* set current page button to active *@
    var $currentButton = $buttons.eq(jsonObject.page - 1);
    $currentButton.addClass("active");
  }

</script>

...

@Html.PagedListPager(
  Model.Items, 
  page => Url.Action("RenderMessageListItems", new {page}), 
  PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
    new PagedListRenderOptions {Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never},
    new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "OnPageChanged"}
  )
)
```

As you can see, the code in `OnPageChanged()` fixes the non-working parts of `PagedListPager`. Sadly i cannot use nice functions like next / previous page buttons as this isn't rendered correctly by `PagedListPager` either.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the control not refreshing the current page button, but in my case I used a variable not named "page", which (as it seems) is required by the control to work properly.